# building ltrace for android

Tags: android, ltrace

I'm trying to build ltrace for android. I've tryed a few ways none worked....

I was able to produce a bin file compiling the source code using crosstool-ng's arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi and

```
./configure -host=arm-linux-gnueabi -target arm-linux-gnueabi CC=/path/to/toolchain/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -prefix=/path/to/destination/folder
```

but when i tried to execute that bin on android i get:

```
./ltrace: not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's too late for you, but this is basically a problem of using a different toolchain. You should either use android toolchain (or probably just the android build system) or build it statically, so it's not dependent on correct system libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your probably have the wrong path to the dynamic linker inside the ltrace binary. On android the linker lives in /system/bin/linker. By default the path will be /bin/ld-linux.so. The way to go is to either port ltrace to work with the Android NDK, build some sample code with Android NDK and figure out all the build flags, link statically, or just find a working pre-built ltrace. I am in the process of solving this problem right now, will post when I have results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like executable bit is not set? You can check by doing `ls -l ltrace` and if needed, set it with `chmod a+x ltrace`.

Comment: It is. ls -l:

     -rwxrwxrwx root     root       114792 2010-05-05 12:02 ltrace

Comment: check if the parition you use is not mounted with `noexec` (by i.e. `cat /etc/mtab`)

Comment: before giving exec permission trough chmod i get permission denied. I don't think it's exec permission. I'm executing from /data/local