# Build android ltrace

Tags: android, linux, build, android-source, strace

Need help building ($ANDROID)/external/ltrace as part of AOSP Android 6.0.

How do you build a version of Android with the external programs, specifically ltrace (source code is under $(ANDROID)/external)? I followed these steps (https://source.android.com/source/devices.html) and was able to compile / build / and then port AOSP image of Android 6.0.1, but I don’t know how to add the external files to the build too. After building, I tried running:

mm ltrace
mma ltrace
make ltrace

and the result was an error all three times. The interesting thing is that tcpdump and strace (both of which are under /external and compiled and built into the the resulting image (ie under system/bin). Any help?

thanks!

I've seen these posts that address similar questions but don't provide sufficient answers.  I would like to build the sources included in AOSP and through AOSP rather than try and compile a version using a linux/gnu cross-compiler.

[building ltrace for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957874/building-ltrace-for-android)
[ltrace for Android build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107795/ltrace-for-android-build)

Comment: So I figured out how it should compile.  I should simply be able to type "make ltrace", however the Android.mk file for ltrace is commented out with a note:  # If you actually want to use ltrace, let android-bionic@ know.
# One of its dependencies (libelf) won't build with clang,
# and we want to know whether anyone actually cares...
ifeq (true,false)

Here is the link to the source:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/ltrace/+/master/Android.mk

Yes I care!  I tried uncommenting out the "ifeq" stmt and ninja started to work but then gave compilation error as expected.

Comment: Well I still have no luck.  I am unable to cross compile trace with elfutils for AARCH target.  I keep on getting this error                                             ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu
......
checking elf.h usability... yes
checking elf.h presence... yes
checking for elf.h... yes
checking gelf.h usability... no
checking gelf.h presence... no
checking for gelf.h... no
configure: error: *** libelf.h or gelf.h not found on your system

What do I do??  i have to get ltrace compiled for use on Android 6.0+ that is running on AARCH64 platform.  Any help?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem??